# Pitch Detection in the Browser

Tags: pitch

Does anybody know a good library that does pitch detection in the browser? Anything in Javascript or Webassembly would suffice. My target is mainly singing voices. I already tried [pitchfinder](https://github.com/peterkhayes/pitchfinder), but for me it reports frequencies that are a half tone to low. Are there any alternatives other than implementing an alorithm your self?

Comment: i never listed code, but i have sorta illustrated an algorithm for pitch detection in a couple of [different](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/22067/what-is-an-amdf/22070#22070) [answers](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/29962/how-to-deal-with-low-fundamental-when-using-amdf-for-pitch-extraction/29968#29968) on this SE.

Comment: Hi Philipp, I'm sorry but asking for code written to a specification (here: pitch detection in the browser) is a bit off-topic here. General question: Doesn't Emscripten allow you to compile any C or C++ to WASM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a samplerate of 48000 instead of 44100.  Or vice versa.

Comment: This kinda solved the issue for me. Pitchfinder by default uses a sample rate 44.1k while Chrome records with 48k.